# ios uitableviewcontroller edit mode

Tags: uitableview, ios, editing

I'm looking the [CoreDataBooks sample](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/CoreDataBooks/Introduction/Intro.html) to manage the data using the uitableviews and I have a question: when I choose a book, appears a table like this:
[image]

and if I press edit, to edit the values I need to go to another view....
it's possible make a think like the contacts app, and edit directly the values cliking?

[image]

thanks!

Comment: developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/… -- the edit view controller has similar functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the [This Example](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/HeaderFooter/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007989) from apple, hopes this helps.

Comment: This is not exactly the solution but it helped me with the design of the view. Thanks *UpVote*